# Uncancel stripe subscription when using subscriptionItems (or remove and add again the subscriptionItem) with handling of subscrition date origin

Tags: javascript, node.js, payment, stripe-payments

I'm working for an online course provider where students can subscribe to mutiple teachers.

Technically, in app subscriptions are represented by a subscription per customer plus a subscriptionItem per teacher subscribed. I use subscriptionItems as this is the recommanded way to handle multiple subscriptions.

### The problem

In my scenario, the student subscribes to teacherA. Some months after, the student unsubscribes from teacherA. He still have access to teacherA's premium content until the end of the subscription period because he paid for it (billing happens at the beginning of the subscription period). Some weeks later he changes his mind and resubscribe...

**What happen if he REsubscribe before the end of the subscription month he already have paid for ?**

My wish is that when I add the subscriptionItem with the same price, it acts like he has never unsubscribed. But is not that clear when I read the docs.

Have you got a clue on how to handle such a scenario ?

### My researches

I found how to **delete** subscriptionItems, but I didn't find any reference on how to reenable/add back those subscriptionItems and REbilling the customer **with respect to the monthly date of subscription** and without extra billing.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you manage your Products, you may wish to consider an entirely new Subscription. If the Customer is re-susbuscribing to the same general "Premium" service, keeping the same would make sense. If they are now subscribing to some "Premium B" (where before they subscribed to "Premium A") then may a new subscription would be better.

To answer you question though, you can r[e-activate subscriptions set to cancel](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/cancel#reactivating-canceled-subscriptions) at period end (but which are still active), you can just [update the subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at_period_end) and set `cancel_at_period_end=false` and the subscription will continue as normal. You can update `items` to change the Plan/Price if needed, or leave the existing ones in place.

If the subscription is no longer active, you will need to create a new subscription.

**Update**:
To replace the price on the existing subscription item while undoing a cancellation you'd send a request like this:

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscriptions/sub_123 \
  -u sk_test_123: \
  -d cancel_at_period_end=false \
  -d 'items[0][id]=si_456' \
  -d 'items[0][price]=price_789'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but that didn't exactly answer my question. "new subscription would be better", in the doc stripe recommend going with subscriptionItems instead of subscriptions, and subscriptions are limited to 25 per customers...see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783389/stripe-charge-bill-customer-immediately-when-adding-a-subscriptionitem-to-an-al/63784725#63784725
I also knew about the second part. But here I'm talking about subscriptionItems, not subscription itself. However thanks for your efforts ^^

Comment: I thought you meant that Subscription A had Service B but was set to cancel, then the Customer subscribes to Service C before the end of the period. Which means you can update the subscription to stop the pending cancellation and replace the subscription items. Not sure where how the 25 item limitation would apply here. Can you explain more what you mean?

Comment: I think the suggestion answer still applies. Undo the pending cancellation and update the `items`. You can either replace the Price on and existing item or ad/remove items as needed.

Comment: I m not willing to cancel the subscription. However, this sounds a bit like a hack. I will just make a scheduler and manually add the subscriptionItem at the next monthly subscription date. I'm not the only one concerned with this issue: https://blog.bigpicture.io/hitting-the-limits-of-stripe/. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you explain why the answer doesn't meet your needs? I did not suggest cancelling the subscription.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I understand "Undo the pending cancellation". Can we cancel subscriptionItems independently ? Also, for " you may wish to consider an entirely new Subscription", why do I need to deal with a new subscription? How can I deal with previous subscriptionItems and the "cancelled" one without extra cost for the customer ? Also when you say "re-activate subscriptions set to cancel", didn't you mean cancel the subscription? Sorry if my questions seems dumb but I may not get your point.

Comment: You're talking about subscriptions set to cancel at period end, which means you updated with `cancel_at_period_end=true`. You can "undo" this (before the period ends) with `cancel_at_period_end=false` to continue the subscription instead. You don't cancel subscription items, but you can modify them (change price, quantity, add/remove etc). You need to 1. undo the cancellation and 2. replace the price or remove/add subscription items for your new plan.